# jade template helpers in node.js and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I use Jade templates both in express app and in the browser. I need to format data before placing it in inputs.

Should I extend locals with alike both in node.js and in browser?

```
{ formatDate: function(date) {}, ... }
```

Or are there any best practices to pass helper functions (e.g. to format money, dates etc.) to jade templates?

Comment: I believe that extending the locals on both sides is the right track, except I'd wrap it up in a namespace within locals, e.g. `helpers: { ... }`.  That'll keep things clean and in one place, and avoid any collision.  Write the module to be both node & browser friendly and drop it in a shared directory where you can pull it in on both sides.  On the browser side, just implement a `render` function that extend the locals automatically; on the node side, just add it to `res.locals`.

Comment: An alternative would be to go with the more "logic-less" route and preprocess your data to be template-ready, eliminating the need for helpers.  Depending on the complexity of your templates it might be a possibility.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up extending locals both server- and client-side.